# Bus Error: 10 in C while inputing text from .txt file into nodes

Tags: c, arrays, linked-list, malloc, bus-error

The code I am trying to implement is a method that reads a .txt file and converts the strings into nodes. Essentially, as I am reading the .txt file, I first check for non-letters (the word cannot start with a number, nor can the word have a non-alphanumerical in any index of the word). Once it finds the first letter, then the program exits the loop and enters another one that loops until it sees a space. When I successfully make a word (a word "ends" when there is a space found), I input the word into a linked list.

When I run this, I get a Bus Error: 10. I thought this would be due to the word[b] array, but when I malloc it, I still get the same error.

Thank you in advance!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define TRUE 1
#define FALSE 0


struct Node{
   char value[100];
   int numOccur;
   int numVariance;
   struct Node *next;
};

void testprint(struct Node * head){
    int data;
    data = head->value;
    strcpy(data,head->value);
    while(head != NULL){

        printf("%s\n", data);
        head = head->next;
    }

}

int main()
{
   struct Node *curr;
   struct Node *n;
   struct Node *head =0;
   struct Node *tail =0;
   struct Node *next;
   char word[100];
   int a;
   int x;



   FILE *file1;
   file1 = fopen("test1.txt", "r");           //opens text file

   if(file1 == NULL){
       fprintf(stderr,"Error: Could not open file");     //if file1 has error, returns    error message
   exit(1);
   }
   a = fgetc(file1);
   int b = 0;
   while(a != EOF){
       while(!isalpha(a)){
           a = fgetc(file1);
           continue;
       }

       n = (struct Node *) malloc( sizeof( struct Node));
       while(isalnum(a)){
           while( a != ' ' && a != EOF){
               word[b] = a;
               a = fgetc(file1);
               b++;
           }
           word[b] = '\0';
       }
       n->next = 0;
       if(head == 0){
           head = n;
           tail = n;
       }
       else{
           tail->next = n;
           tail = n;
       }
   }
    testprint(head);
    fclose(file1);
}
```

Comment: Your code doesn't even compile. There are many errors. You call testprint() with a FILE* when it expects a Node*. Also, the data types don't match when you do word[b] = (char *) malloc( sizeof( char )*30). You are allocating a dynamic char array (lhs) and assigning it to a char (rhs).

Comment: Among the things wrong in this code, '/0' is not a terminating null char; '\0' is. and in fact, to avoid the problem from *ever* cropping up again, don't use *either*. Use `0` instead. Also, is it your intention, upon arriving to your first word, to allocate a new 30-char buffer *for ever character* ?? Seems a little overkill, doesn't it? Especially considering you're saving the allocation into an invalid area of memory (of the wrong type) and leaking like a sieve in the process. Take this to [codereview.stackexchange.com](http://codereview.stackexchange.com) and fixing  the *real* problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should pay attention to the warnings from the compiler. (And it's a good idea always to compile with `-Wall -Wextra` to get more warnings.)

As Barney Hsiao has pointed out, `testprint()` is called with a FILE pointer instead of a Node pointer.

---

Unrelated, but if you need *true* and *false* constants, there is a standard header file that will give you these (in lowercase, ie. `true`, `false`).

```
#include <stdbool.h>
```

---

I get the following compiler warnings when compiling this code:

```
$ CFLAGS="-Wall -Wextra" make bus10
cc -Wall -Wextra    bus10.c   -o bus10
bus10.c: In function ‘testprint’:
bus10.c:20:14: warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type
bus10.c: In function ‘main’:
bus10.c:48:8: warning: array subscript has type ‘char’
bus10.c:54:8: warning: array subscript has type ‘char’
bus10.c:68:23: warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type
bus10.c:34:8: warning: unused variable ‘x’
bus10.c:31:17: warning: unused variable ‘next’
bus10.c:27:17: warning: unused variable ‘curr’
bus10.c:74:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function
```

Now some of these are more serious than others. "array subscript has type 'char'" doesn't sound like a problem to me (to be honest, I don't know what it even means). "unused variable" means just that: you've created (declared) a variable and then you never use it. "control reaches end of non-void function" means you have a function that is declared to return a value but the code falls off the bottom without a return statement.

But "assignment from incompatible pointer type" is bad. The word *incompatible* is bad. Line 20 reads:

```
     head = head->next;
```

Line 68 reads:

```
        tail->next = n;
```

It's because

```
struct Node{
   ...
   struct node *next;
};
```

See? `*next` is not a `struct Node` but a `struct node`. Uppercase/Lowercase counts.

---

Ok. Here's a big one. And the compiler didn't say nothing. Well, to be fair, it did. But we didn't know what it meant. Line 33:

```
    char a;
```

What's wrong with that you say? It's a type that holds a character, right? The problem is here:

```
    a = fgetc(file1);
```

Do you see it yet? How about here?

```
    while(a != EOF){
```

EOF is a sentinel value that is too big to fit in a `char`. It's supposed to be like this. In order for the `fgetc` function to tell you that an End Of File condition occurred and not just another byte from the file it has to return a value outside of the range of a char (0..255 unsigned, -128..127 signed). The `while` condition will never fail because no `char` value can compare equal to EOF.

So declare `a` to be `int`, not `char`.

Comment: Agreed. But still, *first things first*.

Comment: Well in that case, `struct node *next;`, then `int a` instead of `char a`, at most inside while-loop, `while( a != ' '){` doesn't test for EOF so it overruns the char buffer with EOF (and thats the bus error, btw). etc.

Comment: I've been using the GCC compiler. and in my edit, I changed the testprint()  input to a Node pointer

Comment: It'd be good to add the compiler warnings to the question. We can help explain what they mean.

Comment: @luserdroog I changed it to struct Node; however, it still doesn't run. I made the edits in the code above.

Comment: @WhozCraig did I add the testing of the EOF in the right place?

Comment: @user2074228 See my new edit. It's the *type* that's the problem.

Comment: Upon making the changes, I no longer have a bus error. However, nothing prints out now

Comment: Check your logic. I think you want `&&` instead of `||`. (And don't feel bad. I do this one all the time. It's just that I know to check this first when it doesn't work.)

Comment: @luserdroog I changed it to an int, but nothing is printed

Comment: I think you're overrunning the `word` array. Make sure `b` isn't larger than 99 before accessing word[b].

Comment: @luserdroog I made the input file much fewer than 100 characters, so I don't think there's an issue with that...so sorry...

Comment: `b` is not getting reset to 0, it just gets bigger and bigger. To reset it to 0, add `b = 0;` near the `malloc` call. And it's always a good idea to check boundaries.

Comment: Unfortunately it still doesn't work :( any other possible suggestions?

Comment: `testprint` is trying to print head->value. You should `strcpy` the word data in there first.

Comment: Well, think about it. Where is the data coming from? First it's in the file. Then it's in `a` briefly before being moved to `word`. And then later you want to get it out of a dynamic (struct Node).value. So you need `strcpy(n->value,word);` just after you add the nul-termination. Oh, and you probably want to do the nul-termination outside of the loop.